# timelineScrubber issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have made a timeline scrubber. It is working but I am facing a few problems.

1. When I click at the end of the track, the scrubber should go and stop at the end of the slider track but instead it goes to end of track, then jumps to to start of animation and replays the animation.
2. Scrubber does not move smoothly. It is kind of stuck. It does not move freely.

I have attached the fla file in case someone wants to see it. the link is http://www.mediafire.com/?cyk84zf0ndq6r. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var barLength : Number = slider_mc.bar.width - slider_mc.scrub.width;
var rect : Rectangle = new Rectangle (slider_mc.bar.x, slider_mc.scrub.y, barLength, 0);
var moviePlaying:Boolean = true;

slider_mc.scrub.buttonMode = true;
slider_mc.scrub.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.scrubMouseDownHandler);

function scrubMouseDownHandler (event : MouseEvent) : void {
  this.addEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame);     
  slider_mc.scrub.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubMouseMoveHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.scrubRemoveListenerHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this.scrubRemoveListenerHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.startDrag (false, rect);
}

function scrubMouseMoveHandler (event : MouseEvent) : void  {
  var spanPercentage : Number = (slider_mc.scrub.x - slider_mc.bar.x) / barLength;
  var framePosition : int = int (animationMc.totalFrames * spanPercentage);
  if (framePosition < 1) framePosition = 1 ;        
  slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX = ((440/animationMc.totalFrames) * animationMc.currentFrame);
  //trace (framePosition);
  if (moviePlaying==true) {
    animationMc.gotoAndPlay(framePosition);
    //moviePlaying = false;
  } else if(moviePlaying==false) {
    animationMc.gotoAndStop(framePosition);
  }
}

function scrubRemoveListenerHandler (event : MouseEvent) : void  {
  slider_mc.scrub.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubMouseMoveHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.scrubRemoveListenerHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this.scrubRemoveListenerHandler);
  slider_mc.scrub.stopDrag ();
}

slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.width = 0;
this.addEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event) {
  //By default scrub keeps on moving along with animation at the start of swf, when it is published
  //sl.value = this.currentFrame;
  slider_mc.scrub.x = Math.floor((barLength/animationMc.totalFrames) * animationMc.currentFrame);

  //it causes fill to scale along with scrub
  slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX((440/animationMc.totalFrames) * animationMc.currentFrame);


  /////CURRENT TIME///
  var currentSeconds = Math.floor(animationMc.currentFrame/24);
  var CurrentInput = currentSeconds;

  var timeElapsed = (CurrentInput > 3600 ? Math.floor(CurrentInput/3600) + ':':'') //hours
    +(CurrentInput%3600 < 600 ? '0':'')+Math.floor(CurrentInput%3600/60)+':' //minutes
    +(CurrentInput%60 < 10 ? '0':'')+CurrentInput%60; //seconds

  //trace(timeElapsed);
  currentTime.text = timeElapsed;
}


pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseAnim);
function pauseAnim(event:MouseEvent):void {
  //this.removeEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame);
  moviePlaying = false;
  animationMc.stop();
}

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAnim);
function playAnim(event:MouseEvent):void{
  this.addEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame);
  moviePlaying = true;
  animationMc.play();
}

slider_mc.buttonMode = true;
slider_mc.useHandCursor = true;

slider_mc.bar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, snapTo);
function snapTo(event:MouseEvent) {
  slider_mc.scrub.x = mouseX;
  //slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX =((440/animationMc.totalFrames) * animationMc.currentFrame);

  var spanPercentage : Number = (slider_mc.scrub.x - slider_mc.bar.x) / barLength;
  var framePosition : int = int (animationMc.totalFrames * spanPercentage);
  slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX =((440/animationMc.totalFrames) * animationMc.currentFrame);

  //trace (framePosition);

  if (moviePlaying==true) {
    animationMc.gotoAndPlay(framePosition);
    //moviePlaying = false;
  } else if(moviePlaying==false) {
    animationMc.gotoAndStop(framePosition);
  }
}

///better because it gives to leading zeros///////////
//TOTAL TIME///
var totalSeconds = Math.floor(animationMc.totalFrames/24);
var input = totalSeconds;

var totalAnimTime = (input > 3600 ? Math.floor(input/3600) + ':':'') //hours
  + (input%3600 < 600 ? '0':'') + Math.floor(input%3600/60)+':' //minutes
  + (input%60 < 10 ? '0':'') + input%60; //seconds

//trace(totalAnimTime);
totaltime.text = "/"+totalAnimTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the problem is your spanPercentage calculation near line 106. If you click close to the end, it can be a number > 1, giving you a framePosition that is greater than the frames in your animationMc.

Because you can't move a play head past the number of frames, it returns to the first frame.

The quick fix is to make spanPercentage = 1 if spanPercentage > 1. Below are the relevant lines.

```
function snapTo (event:MouseEvent){

    slider_mc.scrub.x = mouseX;
    //trace("mouseX: "+root.mouseX , slider_mc.scrub.x);
    trace("animationMc.currentFrame: "+ Math.floor((barLength/animationMc.totalFrames)* animationMc.currentFrame));

    //slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX=((440/animationMc.totalFrames)*animationMc.currentFrame);

    var spanPercentage : Number = (slider_mc.scrub.x - slider_mc.bar.x) / barLength;
    trace("spanPercentage: " +spanPercentage);
    if(spanPercentage > 1){
        spanPercentage = 1;
    }
    var framePosition : int = int (animationMc.totalFrames * spanPercentage);

    slider_mc.bar.sliderFill_mc.scaleX=((440/animationMc.totalFrames)*animationMc.currentFrame)
    //trace (framePosition);



    if (moviePlaying==true){
        animationMc.gotoAndPlay(framePosition);
        //moviePlaying = false;
    }
    else if(moviePlaying==false) {
        animationMc.gotoAndStop(framePosition);
    }

}
```

1. Your slider_mc instance was stretched on the stage from 440 to 574.
   Returning it to it's proper size of 440 pixels wide fixes your funky scrubber.

Check it out in action and download:
http://micromedia.vaniercollege.qc.ca/home/nortonb/2011-12/flash2/stackoverflow/scrubber.htm

Comment: Thank you so much. You definitely have solved the first problem I mentioned. It is no longer jumping and replaying the animation. Could you suggest how I can overcome the second problem. When I try to drag the scrubber, it just drops midway. I am not able to drag the scrubber the entire lenght of track in one go

Comment: I am very excited. I have posted questions here many times but this is the first time my problem has been solved, although partially. Once again thank you sooo much.

Comment: hi Sanjay. Thought I had solved the second problem, but went back and see that I wasn't testing dragging the scrubber, only clicking on the bar. Haven't solved it yet, but problem is related to disabling the onEnterFrame event so that it doesn't override the drag. Let me know if you want me to do it for you.

Comment: Hi Norton, as you had suggested, I added this.removeEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame); to both scrubMouseDownHandler
and scrubMouseMoveHandler functions and added the line 
this.addEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame); in scrubRemoveListenerHandler but still it is difficult first to catch hold of the scrubber and if you do manage to catch it, then it is still difficult to drag it backwards. If I don't add the enterframe event in mouse up and mouse out handlers, then scrubber and slider fill go out of sync.

Comment: I think spanPercentage is the culprit. Am I right Norton? How can I make it uniform, any ideas???

Comment: anyway thanks Bruce.Norton. I have solved the problem. You like dogs, don't you

Comment: Good for you. Good idea to post your solution for others.